# Inner join combined with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with this one, as it says I cannot join them, do you see any issue?

There are 2 tables involved:

Sales_data:

[image]

Country Master Data:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE sales_cp (
    id      int primary key identity(1,1), 
    country varchar(50), 
    region  varchar(50), 
    product varchar(50), 
    revenue numeric(18,0)
)

INSERT INTO sales_cp ( country, Region, Product, revenue )
SELECT
    sales_data    .country, 
    Country_Master.Region,
    sales_data    .item_type,
    sum( Sales_Data.Total_revenue ) AS Revenue
FROM
    sales_data 
    INNER JOIN sales_cp ON Country_Master.Country = sales_data.country
GROUP BY sales_data.country, sales_data.item_type
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing sample data for `sales_data` and `sales_cp` . You need to create a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: That said, your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause - is that intentional? (I assume you're after sales data-by-country rather than a single row)

Comment: @Dai is right you are missing group by

Comment: When using an aggregate function, in your case `sum`, all columns in the select statement except the sum itself (there are some exceptions but this is the general rule)  need to be part of the group by, so after your edit you are missing the `region` field on the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the Country_Master table in the join and use every column in the `group by` other than aggregated columns.

Following should work:

```
INSERT INTO sales_cp ( country, Region, Product, revenue )
SELECT
    sales_data    .country, 
    Country_Master.Region,
    sales_data    .item_type,
    sum(Sales_Data.Total_revenue) AS Revenue
FROM
    sales_data 
    INNER JOIN Country_Master ON Country_Master.Country = sales_data.country  --correctly using Country_Master table here
GROUP BY sales_data.country, sales_data.item_type, Country_Master.Region --added Region as well
```